# UNION based on common column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have 2 tables:

[image]

And I want to create UNION query, based on the common rows of EAN. Like, in the end, I want my table to look like:
[image]

Any helps would be really appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which dbms are you really using?

Comment: @HoneyBadger it is in Google BigQuery

Comment: Then why did you tag mysql and postgresql?

Comment: because whoever has knowledge in SQL could help or at least give a direction,  afak :) @HoneyBadger

Comment: I removed the incompatible tags. Please only tag products involved

Comment: Where does the company "3" come from?

Comment: I guess company 3 should be found in place of the current 3 1's in Table 2...also, better add ean="ijk" in Table 1 and illustrate whether it should be included in the outcome. From description, I guess no but this will help to make things clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this ?

```
SELECT
  a.ean,
  a.price,
  a.company,
  a.lowestPrice
FROM
  Table1 a
UNION
SELECT
  b.ean,
  b.price,
  b.company,
  NULL AS lowestPrice
FROM
  Table2 b 
  INNER JOIN Table1 c ON c.ean = b.ean
```

Comment: This is, unfortunately, returning me also all EANs from Table2, however, I want all rows from Table 2 which has common rows of EAN with Table 1. @Tharuka

Answer (score 2):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.table1` UNION ALL
  SELECT *, NULL AS company FROM `project.dataset.table2`
)
WHERE ean IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT ean
  FROM `project.dataset.table1` 
  JOIN `project.dataset.table2` 
  USING (ean)
)
```

When applied to sample data from your question - output is

```
Row ean price   company lowestPrice  
1   abc 12      1       12   
2   abc 23      2       12   
3   fgh 43      1       43   
4   fgh 82      2       43   
5   abc 21      1       null     
6   fgh 54      1       null
```